# C# 6 syntax in Razor View

Tags: razor, c#-6.0

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["LoginProvider"]?.ToString() ?? null" />
```

When the `ViewData` is null, it makes a `half-conversion` and the hidden field contains value: `?.ToString() ?? null`

I'm sure that I've enabled C# 6:

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
</compiler>
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with the ?? operator, the left hand value is string and the right hand value is null, therefore, it is not a correct syntax. Also, since there is an assignment operation involved, you need to wrap them in parenthesis.

You can try the following:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@(ViewData["LoginProvider"]?.ToString() ?? "")" />
```